# Android how to prevent overwriting the previous TextView?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

What I am doing: 
I read an `EditText` input and try to display it as `TextView` by clicking a `Button`.

What I need:
Eg.If Edittext1 is Apple, 
Textview1 is Apple and if
Edittext2 is Orange,
Textview2 is Apple
Orange(Orange on a new line)

My problem:
When I am performing the above step for the second `EditText` input, the first `TextView` display is replaced.
Eg. If Edittext1 isApple,
Textview1 is Apple and if 
Edittext2 is Orange,
Textview2 is Orange

If anybody knows the solution for this, please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this : `yourTextView.append("\nOrange");`

Comment: Thanks for the "append"... I had used setText. :-)

Comment: @VyshnavRamesh if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("apple"){
    textView1.setText("Apple");
}
if(editText2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("orange") && editText1.getText().toSting().equalsIgnoreCase("apple")){
    textView2.setText("Apple\nOrange");
}
```

If you can share your code I can give you exact code which will work for you

Comment: Thank you for the help. Ishould have used "append)"